# Wrong specialchar order with scandir

Tags: php

scandir sorts underline after numeric and other special chars:
How can i sort directorys the expected way?

```
 $files = scandir($dir);
```

... sorts to:

```
/first
/first/,om
/first/0go_for_it
/first/1oho
/first/2ond
/first/_des
/first/_des/go
/first/_des/start
/first/_mh
/first/klassen
/first/wow
```

Comment: What **is** "the expected way?"

Comment: specialchars first...

Comment: Well you can use `asort()` or `uasort()` on your `scandir()` array.

Comment: yes, i will do this. The sorting ist just curious, cause of the comma that comes on top, and underlines after.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do anything with it but you can sort the result using your own algorithm using [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function